# Retrieve data from json using arrays

Tags: javascript, json

Can someone help me with the code below:

Why is alert not firing with the correct data...

```
<script>
    var data = {'A':'Apple','B':'Ball','C':'Cat','D':'dog','E':'Elephant'};
    var arr = ['B','C','A','E','D'];
    var text = "<table border=1>";
    for(var k=0; k<arr.length; k++) {
       alert(data.code);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a Javascript object. JSON is a text format for representing data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be alerting `data[arr[k]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `object[key]` syntax (rather than `object.key`) to access the contents of `data` since your `key` is a variable.

```
var data = {'A':'Apple','B':'Ball','C':'Cat','D':'dog','E':'Elephant'};
var arr = ['B','C','A','E','D'];

for (var k=0; k < arr.length; k++) {
   var key = arr[k];   // get the actual element from "arr"
   alert(data[key]);   // and then the element with that key from "data'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<script>
    var data = {'A':'Apple','B':'Ball','C':'Cat','D':'dog','E':'Elephant'};
    var arr = ['B','C','A','E','D'];
    var text = "<table border=1>";
    for(var k=0; k<arr.length; k++)
    {
       alert(data[arr[k]]);
    }
</script>
```